# Beautify HTML Code in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

How can I do this? I have Package Control installed and I'm running Ubuntu. There are similar questions that detail some faulty plugins, and I'm wondering if this is still the case as of 2014

Comment: what language(s) are you trying to beautify? Have you tried [searching Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/search)?

Answer (score 9):

Check out [`HTML-CSS-JS Prettify`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/HTML-CSS-JS%20Prettify). It requires `node.js` to work, so make sure you read through the entire README to get your system set up properly. I've been using it for a while, and I really like it. There are lots of configuration options, so you can customize it to your particular needs.